# Android: How to structure GPS Logging feature in LBS App

Tags: android, gps

I am planning to add a feature to an existing Android App. Because I don't have any experience in programming Android Apps I want to know how I can implement such a feature. I already researched for some time about it and also did some tutorials concerning Android Apps.

My idea at the moment looks like this:

I have an application that starts a normal `Activity` for the user to do something. This `Activity` already exists and should not be my concern. `onCreate()` it should additionally start a Service that will regulary request a Location update  inside a `while(true)`-loop and send the result to a `ContentProvider` that will store the nessesary information in a `SQLite` db.

Also there should be a new menuitem to start a `Gmaps` view which will trigger the `Gmaps` `Activity` which then loads in an `AsyncTask` the stored locations from the db for presentation in the `Gmap`.

`onDestroy()` it will ask the user in a short `Dialog` if he likes to shut the logging `Service` down or continue that the user can later review his trip on `Gmaps`.

Is it possible to create a feature in this way? Do I need to add something else or do parts of it in a different fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> onCreate() it should additionally start a Service that will regulary request a Location update inside a while(true)-loop and send the result to a ContentProvider that will store the nessesary information in a SQLite db.

This is not a good idea. `LocationManager` helps you achieve this via a listener. It looks like you have missed http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html. Another good resource is http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Comment: so instead of the Service I let the LocationManager work? Is that correct? Can that also handle the case that the user might wants to shut down the App but still wants the logging to continue?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I was talking about using the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html instead of polling the LocationManager. As for using/not using a Service, the question you should ask yourself is "is this operation (keeping track of the location) required irrespective of whether the user is using the app?". If you do, use a Service.